# Find 10 closest matches of a 30 dimensional vector, what data structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, nearest-neighbor

I got a vector with 30 dimensions and I want to find the 10 closest matches in my database. I have around 3000 vectors in my DB which I’ve to compare it to. Some dimensions are more important than others so I want to give them all separate weights.

The 30 dimensions are buildup out of 10 times RGB values. I split a picture in to 9 tiles. So 9 * 3 (RGB) 27. And the last three values are the RGB of the mean color of the picture.

My question is: Is this possible, if so. What is the best way to make this process as quick and efficient as possible? Myself, I was thinking about some sort of tree but there are so many trees I don’t know which one is most suitable for my problem.

Edit:

I guess I wasn’t totally clear on what I wanted to achieve. I have a random vector and I want to compare this one with the vectors in my DB to find the 10 closed. I have a DB with all my vectors. I have stored them in a MySQL DB every row is a vector. See below

[image: DB]

Comment: How you store 30-dimension vectors in your database?

Comment: Storing a custom tree in a (relational) database doesn't seem possible to do in a manner useful for performance.

Comment: Only 3000 of them? Just brute force

Comment: What do you mean by "find the 10 closest matches"? Do you have some reference vector V and you want to find 10 vectors from your set that have the smallest distance from V ? Or you want to find a group of 10 vectors from your set that satisfy some condition of being "closest matches" with respect to the other ones?

Comment: @Krystian I assume "closest to some input" is meant.

Comment: Hey, 30 dimensional vector?? If you have just length==2 for each dimension, you will get around 1000000000 (one billion) values in your array. Maybe you mean 30-length vector, not 30-dimensional?

Comment: @SergeyS: vector of length 30 is exactly a point in 30-dimensional vector space, nothing strange about that.

Comment: OP most likely means a length of 30, as "10 times RGB values" would imply 10 3-tuples.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to the problem of finding the n closest points to a reference point when you have got too many of them.

Assuming you know how to compare two vectors to find the "distance" between them, you can use a max heap for this. Use the distance from the random vector as the key for comparing two vectors from the db. That is,

1. Find the distance of the random vector from the first 10 vectors in the database and store them in a max heap of size 10. The root will thus be the vector which is farthest from the random vector till now.
2. Compare and find the distance from the random vector to all the other vectors one by one.
3. For each comparison, if the distance found is less than the root of the max heap, then extract the max element from the heap and insert the latest vector in the heap.
4. At the end, you will have the 10 closest vectors in your heap.

That said, your problem space seems really small. So, you can just use brute force as suggested in the comments.